# How to plot histograms in Python using JES

Tags: python, plot

I need to write a Python program in JES that reads a text file, separates it into words, and plots the frequencies of these words in two different ways.

Basically, I need to, 1. Read a file of text and form a list of the distinct words in the text and the number of times each distinct word appears in the text. and 2. Plot a vertical histogram of the words and their frequencies.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after is creating a few empty lists. One that plots the words and one that plots the frequencies and then printing them together. Then I would be using those lists for the histogram!